# Data relationship between a data extension and the Subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud

I noticed that it is possible to define a data relationship between a Subscriber field and a data extension. Also see [here](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/procedures/#How_to_Create_a_Data_Relationship) "You can also include the subscriber record if you're relating a data extension to a subscriber attribute"
The normal approach would be to link two data extensions instead.

So the question is: once I created the link (see screenshot [image]), how and where in the application would I filter the subscribers according to this relationship? It looks like I am not able to find it. It that is the case, I am wondering why the application allows you to define such link.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the little information box in your screenshot you will actually notice the sentence: "For this relationship to be used inside a Data Filter, both related items must be Data Extensions".

So it would seem that you cannot use a subscriber attribute as part of a filter through this tool. The actual purpose it serves? Unknown to me too! Maybe somebody else knows what the point of data relationships outside of filtering is...

Comment: It's been this way since the beginning.  What seems like potentially great functionality just hasn't been completely developed yet.  The way around this is to use AMPscript to lookup the Data Extension and retrieve the required data from there.